# Strange issue where <p> tags are not visible in the HTML (trying to problem solve this)

Tags: html

Odd situation here...if I look at a Blog Post I see that there are no paragraph tags in the code (when looked at from the View Source Code) in the browser.

However, when I go to the post as an admin, and I view the Code Editor, I see this:

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Content</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Content</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

So...all good....then when I click Update, and refresh the page, the paragraphs appear and all is well.

It therefore seems that if I save the post and refresh then WordPress triggers the publishing of these tags and they remain in place thereafter.

Is there a way to "flush" a WordPress install to trigger the activation of the paragraph tags on all posts?

Thanks for all help with this

Comment: Is this causing any problems? Posts published using the classic editor do not include the p tags, because the classic editor supported creating paragraphs using line breaks in the text editor. If you update a post using the block editor then they will be converted to paragraph blocks, which look like this. The only way to trigger this process is using the block editor manually.

Comment: If the paragraph tags aren’t appearing on the front end, then your theme is probably doing something wrong. Is your theme using the_content() to output post content?